# Should `ImportDeclaration.moduleSpecifier` always be StringLiterial?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

```
interface ImportDeclaration extends Statement {
    kind: SyntaxKind.ImportDeclaration;
    importClause?: ImportClause;
    moduleSpecifier: Expression;
}
```

I can't find a use case that `moduleSpecifier` is not a `StringLiteral`

Answer (score 1):

It must be for the rest of the compiler, but is specified more generally as the `Expression` type so that the parser can gracefully recover and store it in its tree.

Check out [this comment from the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.9.1/src/compiler/parser.ts#L6106-L6108).

> ```
> // We allow arbitrary expressions here, even though the grammar only allows string
> // literals.  We check to ensure that it is only a string literal later in the grammar
> // check pass.
> ```

[image: The text <code>import foo from wat</code>, where <code>wat</code> has a red underline indicating a syntax error (i.e. "String literal expected.")]

All text within a file has to belong to some Node in its corresponding tree. In cases like the one above, we want to report an error on the `Identifier` named `wat`.

Since we report grammar errors *after* parsing, then whatever the expression is, it needs to be on the `importSpecifier`. Otherwise, how would we know what the node *should* have been? The context of being owned by an `ImportDeclaration` allows us to know after parsing that we need to report a parse error.

As you mentioned, this comes at a cost - all users of `importSpecifier` have to handle the more general case where `importSpecifier` is an expression. This is definitely painful, and I unfortunately don't have a great workaround for you on that.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. However, this comment describes what does, but doesn't describe why it does that. Looking at the code, it seems like it is because both `import` and `export` uses that function. Maybe one way to improve it is to make it a generic function to return the proper type?
Why I ask is because it is confusing for `ImportDeclaration.moduleSpecifier` to be not `StringLiteral`, make people wonder what else can it be, and need to perform additional cast to get `.text`.

Comment: I see. Do you mean that if `importSpecifier` is `StringLiteral`, then the whole import statement will fail to parse, and the whole statement will be an error? Currently, we can isolate the error to the `importSpecifier` expression and report the error as in the screenshot.

Comment: No, it will succeed in parsing, but an error will be reported if something like an identifier is present instead.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't that is the current behavior?